# Querying JSON Object in BIg Query

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have a json object in a column that looks like this

```
{
 "user.id": "635bdb70dc89a6e30cde1193",
 "user.firstname":"John"
}
```

I will like to destructure it and select only the firstname,
I have tried

```
SELECT 
JSON_VALUE(user_properties, '$.user.firstname') AS firstname,
```

but no luck

Comment: try  JSON_VALUE(user_properties, '$."user.firstname"') instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can quote it

```
Select JSON_VALUE(user_properties,'$."user.firstname"')
```

Or you can use a CROSS APPLY and OPENJSON

```
SELECT j.* 
FROM YourTable A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(user_properties)
            WITH 
            (
                [user.firstname] VARCHAR(50)
            ) j;
```